# Install Ubuntu alongside Windows10, cannot start Ubuntu

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, grub

I already have Windows10 on SSD. I want to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on HDD. I made the partition and started to install it, it did not ask the location for installation and arranged it itself. But when I restart my laptop, windows started, the grub screen did not show up. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

### From Windows 10 side

1. Start Windows 10.
2. Run `cmd` as Administrator.
3. type this command: `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`
4. Restart and I hope You’ll be welcomed by the familiar Grub screen.

If the above entry didn’t change anything, you can reverse it using the command below:

```
bcdedit /deletevalue {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

Even if the above command didn’t work, try the command below to set the boot back to Windows.

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
```

### From live Ubuntu media (DVD or USB) side

**Source:** https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc?answertab=active#tab-top

1. Insert or connect the Ubuntu live media (DVD or USB).
2. Find out how to [boot your computer from removable media](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD).

   Note that there is a [difference between booting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Identifying_if_the_computer_boots_the_Ubuntu_DVD_in_EFI_mode) of older computers (BIOS/MBR) and newer ones designed for Windows 8 and later releases (UEFI/GPT).

   Reboot the computer from live media and choose **Try Ubuntu** when asked.

   [image: Try Ubuntu]
3. Connect to the internet, then open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>, paste the following commands and run them by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   ```
   sudo apt install software-properties-common; \
   sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair; \
   sudo apt-get update; \
   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
   ```

   > Note: You copy and run them all at once. If you want to run them individually just remove the trailing "`; \`".

   That's it, the Boot-Repair window will appear!

   [image: Boot-Repair main window]

#### Related:

- https://askubuntu.com/q/38162
- https://askubuntu.com/search?q=Dual+boot+Ubuntu+and+windows+10

Comment: Excellent answer.  I'd just add at the end to click "Recommended repair".

Comment: ROTFL!  I assumed your user name was a self-deprecating reference to being an old-timer.  Then I checked out your home page.  Glad a professional is supporting the professionals.

Comment: @fixer1234 Always happy to help and glad that did not disappoint!

Comment: Thank you for yout attention but  bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi  command did not work for me. I did not mentioned that i could not be able to boot on the first place. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085550/cant-install-ubuntu-18-10-on-xps-15-efi-boot-mmx64-efi-not-found  I tried second solution from the link. I can boot it after that but maybe my setup is completely wrong? Can you help me please?

Comment: @nehiridil What step in second solution wrong for you?

Comment: When I put on USB, I could not be able to boot. I get this error: Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi - Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi: Not Found
Failed to start MokManager: Not Fond
Something has gone seriously wrong: import_mok_state() failed    I followed the steps from the link that I share with you (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085550/cant-install-ubuntu-18-10-on-xps-15-efi-boot-mmx64-efi-not-found) After that I can start installation. Is it proper way to do it? I could not understand why I copy grubx64.efi and renamed "mmx64.efi" on  usb?

Comment: @nehiridil, if you still have a chance to boot from live USB, try Repair-Boot tool from this solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/226061/how-to-install-the-boot-repair-tool-in-an-ubuntu-live-disc?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: I followed the steps but now I cannot start my pc

Comment: @nehiridil You need boot PC from live USB/DVD. In this case work OS installed on USB/DVD. If you need info about live USB folow this steps: https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0